# How to define the likelihood function given exact assumptions?

Tags: bayesian, conditional-probability

I'm trying to model a poorly shuffled deck, where the probabilities of cards showing up in different positions are not uniform.

Example deck with three cards: $c_1, c_2, c_3$. After the poor shuffle
$$
P(c_n\ in\ position\ n) = 0.6\\
P(c_n\ in\ position\ m) = 0.2, m \neq n
$$

I'm trying to predict the cards one by one as they're being drawn from the deck in order (positions 1, 2, 3). What's stumping me is the posterior probabilities for the second card. For example
$$
P(c_1\ in\ position\ 2 | c_2\ in\ position\ 1) = \dfrac{P(c_2\ in\ position\ 1\ |\ c_1\ in\ position\ 2)P(c_1\ in\ position\ 2)}{P(c_2\ in\ position\ 1)}
$$

Probability of drawing $c_1$ next, given the first drawn card was $c_2$.

The likelihood $P(c_2\ in\ position\ 1\ |\ c_1\ in\ position\ 2)$ seems to be as difficult to calculate as the posterior propability itself, rendering the Bayes rule unhelpful. Is there a way to define the likelihood function given the known factors? Or am I applying the Bayes rule wrong? I would like to calculate the posterior propablity in the general case of a poorly shuffled deck, not just the example.

Comment: Likelihood being an heavily used term in statistics, I would suggest using probability or conditional probability instead.